# Databricks: Should you use PySpark or Spark SQL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, databricks

Should I use PySpark or Spark SQL more in Databricks? I know you can't do everything in only one language but what I should use more preferably?

In terms of testing, cost and performance. I'm using Databricks on AWS.

Comment: it depends on what you're doing, and your knowledge of one or other. Under the hood both PySpark & SQL are translated into the same internal representation

Comment: @AlexOtt when you say that, do you mean both languages are still translated into Scala?

Comment: No, all usages of DataFrame API are translated into internal representation of operations that then are optimized & executed. You can check this by checking the execution plans with `.explain` functions on DataFrame, or `explain ...your-query...` in SQL